# Playframework 2.2 resolvers

Tags: playframework-2.0, sbt, deadbolt

In play 2.1 and prior I had to add the resolvers in `Build.scala` like:

```
val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
    resolvers += Resolver.url("Objectify Play Repository", url("http://schaloner.github.io/releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns),
    resolvers += Resolver.url("Objectify Play Snapshot Repository", url("http://schaloner.github.io/snapshots/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
  )
```

In 2.2 I have to put it in `build.sbt` like:

```
...
resolvers += "Objectify Play Snapshot Repository" at "http://schaloner.github.com/snapshots/"
...
```

But that does not seem to work, dependencies are not found.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are adding it as a maven repository but in your old config you are saying that it is ivy repositories, I think it should be something like:

```
resolvers += Resolver.url("Repo-name", url("http://example.com/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
```

Checkout the sbt 0.13 (which play 2.2 uses) docs on resolvers for more info:
http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Resolvers.html

Comment: Hi johanandren, thanks for your answer. I think that would be the case for Play 2.1. But with that I would have duplicate definitions (name and version in build.sbt and Build.scala). I solved it without duplicate definitions. See my answer.

Answer (score 4):

**Update:**

This solution is not working, I had the dependencies in the cache.

I solved it like this:

**project/plugins.sbt**:

```
// Comment to get more information during initialization
logLevel := Level.Warn

// The Typesafe repository
resolvers ++= Seq(
        Resolver.url("Objectify Play Repository", url("http://schaloner.github.io/releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns),
        "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
)

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.0")
```

And then I can add the dependency in **build.sbt**:

```
name := "test"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
  "be.objectify" %% "deadbolt-java" % "2.2-RC1"
)     

play.Project.playJavaSettings
```

Comment: This doesn't work on Play 2.2.1. Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19928495/installing-deadbolt-on-play-framework-2-2-1

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, just add it alone in a new line at the end of `build.sbt`

Check http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/Build

```
name := "my-app"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
...
)     

play.Project.playJavaSettings

resolvers += "itext repository" at "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/maven2/"
```