# Questions about installing Deadbolt on Play 2.2.1

Tags: java, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.2, deadbolt

1. As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19928495/unresolved-dependencies-installing-deadbolt-on-play-framework-2-2-1) if I put the resolvers in `plugins.sbt` Play doesn't see them. But it works if I move them in `build.sbt`. Is there a reason?
2. Another problem: if there isn't the file `play.plugins` I get this error:
   `"**Exception:** The Deadbolt Java plugin was not registered, or is disabled. Please check your conf/play.plugins file."` But it isn't written in any installation guide that `play.plugins` is needed to install Deadbolt (maybe it was needed for older version). [source 1](http://schaloner.github.io/) [source 2](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/play-framework/2.2$20deadbolt/play-framework/hgZve85NyyI/0qPhPYnHOGgJ)

In conclusion, I think there's a big confusion about Deadbolt installation. Someone could clarify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. plugins.sbt is for plugins to sbt, the build tool, so for example you would put a release plugin, or maybe a count lines of code-plugin there, build.sbt is for your actual project so stuff you want to use inside your project goes there
2. for play to load plugins that you have made available on the classpath (either by putting them in the lib/ directory or by adding a managed dependency in you build.sbt) you must always add them to conf/play.plugins. That you need to do that is noted in the deadbolt-2 docs, altough not on the first page of the docs: https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2-guide/blob/master/04-deadbolt-java-hooks.markdown

Comment: Hi johan. Point 1: then putting Deadbolt resolvers in build.sbt is correct and is more correct than into plugins.sbt. Right? Point 2: ok, then why other plugins I'm using (like mysql-connector-java and apache commons-email) work perfectly without putting them in play.plugins? thanks

Comment: 1. yes, correct!
2. mysql-connector-java and apache-commons-email are just libraries, not play plugins - they know nothing of the play application lifecycle while deadbolt wants to plug into play and get created with the application and shut down with the application.

Comment: Perfect, very clear johan. Tried and all works great now. One last thing: when I navigate to a restricted page with an unauthorized user it doesn't access but in the Play console I get this error: `"[error] application - Access to [/restricted-page] requires a subject, but no subject is present.
[warn] application - Deadbolt: Access failure on [/restricted-page]"`. Is it correct that it shows that error?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know, haven't used deadbolt myself, nothing in the deadbolt docs about what is supposed to happen?