# How can I view or hide some data depending of user logged in or not?

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I am testing Play framework 2.2.2. There is a helper for user authentication and seems to be simple to implement it. But if I need to hide some menus or other content from unregistered users - how can I do it?

I am thinking about `if-blocks`:

```
@if(...) {
  <h1>Content for registered users only</h1>
} else {
  <h1>Register to see this content</h1>
}
```

but what will be in the condition block? Have anybody an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [Deadbolt-2](https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2) it's dedicated for **this** job, it allows to show (or hide) content in views depending on logging state but also by **roles** and **permitions**. Also incorporates access control for controller and/or actions.

Optionally you can also look at [Play Authnticate](https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate) it's full authorization/authentication stack - it also uses Deadbolt for mentioned reasons.

Comment: But how can I add `deadbolt-2` libraries into my project? In the https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2#play-22 I have read about `Build.scala`, but I have `build.sbt` in my project root.

Comment: Just add what's required to `libraryDependencies` in build file

Comment: Thanks. I have read posts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19928495/unresolved-dependencies-installing-deadbolt-on-play-framework-2-2-1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19952470/questions-about-installing-deadbolt-on-play-2-2-1. So, I add required lines into `build.sbt` (that is replased Build.scala in new versions of Play) and create `/conf/play.plugins` file with line acording https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2-guide/blob/master/04-deadbolt-java-hooks.markdown#the-deadbolt-plugin